# triple integration to find volume

Tags: integration, volume, bounds-of-integration

how can I solve this problem I already have the final answer but I don't know how to solve it , the answer for this problem is $(V=8(pi-1/3)$
I tried solving it  with this:

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_0^{x^2+y^2}dzdydx$

but it didn't work

Write an iterated triple integral in the order dzdydx for the volume of the region bounded
below by the xy-plane and above by the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ and lying inside the
cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$?

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Switch to spherical coordinates my friend. And don't forget the determinant of the jacobian.

Comment: Tomislav Ostojich can you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to cylindrical coordinates instead. Your integral will change to:
$4 \int_0^2 \int_0^{\pi/2}  \int_0^{\rho^2} \rho dz d\phi d\rho  $

Comment: But I need it in cartesian coordinates

Comment: I suggest you to change the limits to those for quarter of a circle and then multiply by 4 It will give right answer